How can I tell if my version of Typo3 is headless?
I just wanted to ask you how can I know if the version of Typo3 I use are headless or not, as I do not really understand how to idenfy it.
I use the versions 10.4.44 and 11.5.36. I know they can be supported but I am not sure as to how can I know that.
Thank you for your help!
I do not understand how I can identify a headless CMS.

Hi Are you sure you meand Headless? as HeadlessCMS  refers to a CMS which does not directly render the content but rather provides an API to retrive content for some other Application to consume. (like android/iphone apps)
you might mean is your TYPO3 Version Up To Date or still Supported.the current version and End of Support can be seen here https://get.typo3.org/
also there is the "Roadmap" which also includes support time frames for current and and upcoming relases https://typo3.org/cms/roadmap/

Well TYPO3 is only headless if you have installed the headless extension (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/headless), else it is not headless ;)
If installed you should get a JSON Object as result, when you load a page. (https://docs.typo3.org/p/friendsoftypo3/headless/main/en-us/Installation/Index.html)
